# how to get the cmd location?

Tags: c#

i'm using c# .net 4.5;
my question is how could i get the cmd location.
for example to get my own form location i use  `this.Location` and i'm getting the x and the y.
how could i do it for an application which is running but has nothing to do with my own app? i know it's possible because windows 8 use something like that. :)

thanks for helping...

Comment: Location of cmd.exe is "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe"... but I suspect you want something else... but not clear what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question at first glance seems you want the location of the application exe and not the position of the window. If you want the position of the window you need to use API.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Rect
{
    public int left;
    public int top;
    public int right;
    public int bottom;
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref Rect rect
```

And then use it like so:

```
var proc = Process.GetProcessesByName(proccessName)[0];   
Rect rect = new Rect();
GetWindowRect(proc.MainWindowHandle, ref rect);
```

Hope it helps

For more information look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [pInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindowRect.html)